# how to install the doctrine mongodb odm via composer

Tags: php, mongodb, annotations, doctrine, odm

I am working on a project with the php and mongodb stacks. I need the assistance of an ODM to speed up development time. A problem I have now however is this line, 
$ composer require `"doctrine/mongodb-odm=~1.0"`
in which directory should i execute this command, the application's root directory or anywhere in my command line???

Comment: You execute the line `composer require "doctrine/mongodb-odm=~1.0"` in the directory where your `composer.json` file is located.  So in this instance, it would be your application root directory.  If you need further assistance you can type `composer help` for a further list of commands.  Otherwise @Nisha's answer to modify your composer.json file is also valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the following to composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "~1.0",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "~3.0"
    },
}
```

after that run the command in respective folder

```
php composer.phar update doctrine/mongodb-odm doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle
```

Comment: @Sigmabooma If it helped, mark as answer, that might help others too.